# 0 preceding and 0 following in teradata

Tags: teradata

I have just found out that '0 preceding' and '0 following' are not the same things in Teradata SQL. Maybe it's not that important to know the reason behind this, but i`m still curious about that and want to know the logic. So, does anyone know what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Standard SQL there's no difference, both are equivalent to `current row`.

But Teradata seems to do it a bit differenty, when it's a cumulative windows: In `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED/n PRECEDING AND 0 PRECEDING` it's the same as `1 PRECEDING`, very strange.

Of course I can't imagine why anyone will actually use this instead of `current row`.